# Usage of the word "coordinated" in a professional report

Tags: verbs, word-usage, grammaticality

Which is a more apt way of using the word coordinated in the given context:

1. I thank Mr. XYZ, who coordinated with me on the project.
   OR
2. I thank Mr. XYZ, with whom I coordinated on the project.

Note that the sentence should relay prime importance to the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, coördination must be mutual. Therefore to say that he coördinated with you is using the word in precisely the same way as saying the you coördinated with him. Hence there is absolutely no difference between the usage of the word *coördinated* in either sentence.

I'd go with the first to be more direct, avoid the *whom* construction which can trip readers up, and to make the person I'm thanking the actor rather than the patient, but the word itself is used the same either way.

Making both of you the subject might be better still:

> Mr XYZ and I coordinated to produce this project, and I would like to thank him.

Or even better to use the noun:

> This project is the result of considerable coordination between Mr XYZ and myself, so I would like to thank him.

Answer (score 0):

Neither seems quite right. If you both worked together to coordinate the project, then it should be "I thank Mr XYZ , with whom I coordinated the project." Or "... who worked with me to coordinate the project."

Neither "coordinated with me" nor "coordinated on" is a standard construction.

Comment: You've changed the meaning entirely by switching to a different sense of *coördinated*. The OP didn't say that they coördinated the project (either placed in some order or rank, or positioned relative to a system that it is part of), they said that they coördinated with him (worked in combined order to produce a result).

Comment: Hmm. The potential for ambiguity is why I said, "If you both worked together to coordinate the project..." 

It's not entirely clear to me _what_ the OP means, since you don't say that someone else "coordinated with me" if you mean that you both worked together to achieve the result.

The formulations in your answer are good, though, and since the OP has accepted it, you would seem to have the right sense.